# How is a map initialised in memory

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity

I just tarted to write solidity and i have some questions that i could not find the answer to.

When you declare a map like this:

```
struct UserAccount{
    string name;
    uint id;
}

mapping (address => UserAccount) public accounts;
```

How will that be initialised? or with what?

For example, accessing

```
accounts[0x79d66c53ad6f1847288c0d06c01a2b38c38f15bc]
```

will return an instance of an UserAccount? If yes, that means that the map creates an instance of UserAccount for every possible address? Doesn't that consume very much memory? If not, then how comes you can do this:

```
accounts[_address].name = _name;
```

?

And the second question:

I keep reference in my contract of an address that is the owner, the address that created the contract:

```
address public owner;
constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
}
```

After i call this function:

```
uint userCount=0;
mapping (address => UserAccount) public accounts;

function createAccount(string _name, uint _id, address _address) onlyOwner() public {
    UserAccount user;
    user.name = _name;
    user.id = _id;
    accounts[_address] = user;
    userCount += 1;
    // accounts[_address].name = _name;
    // accounts[_address].id = _id;
    // userCount += 1;
    emit UserCreated(_address, _id, _name);
}

modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;        
}
```

the owner address changes. The commented lines from createAccount function are the way to do it, i know, but i want to understand why it does not work.

To clarify my problem i will also post a js test.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    voting = await Voting.new({from: owner});
});

it("Should delete poll, as owner", async () =>{
    var name = "Sandu";
    console.log("LOCAL OWNER= " + owner);
    console.log("OWNER BEFORE CREATE ACCOUNT FROM SOL= " + await voting.owner());
    await voting.createAccount(name, 1, firstUser,{from:owner});
    console.log("OWNER AFTER CREATE ACCOUNT FROM SOL= " + await voting.owner());
    var pollName = "First Poll";
    var endDateS="2018-08-11T10:20:30Z";
    var endDate=new Date(endDateS)
    await voting.createPoll(pollName, 1, endDate.getTime()/1000,{from:firstUser});


    try{
        await voting.deletePollById(1,{from: owner});
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err.message);
    }

    assert.notEqual(pollName, await voting.getPollById(1));
});
```

The test above prints this:

```
LOCAL OWNER= 0x79d66c53ad6f1847288c0d06c01a2b38c38f15bc //Owner that o have in my js file local, first address from the ganache accounts.
OWNER BEFORE CREATE ACCOUNT FROM SOL= 0x79d66c53ad6f1847288c0d06c01a2b38c38f15bc  //The owner account from my contract before calling the function
OWNER AFTER CREATE ACCOUNT FROM SOL= 0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000a   //The owner account from my contract after calling the function
```

I can't understand why the value from owner changes as i don't touch that in my function.

If anyone can help it would be much appreciated. Again, i know the right way to do it but i am posting this out of the desire to understand what i am doing not to get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Please do not post multiple questions in a single post as it will result in the question being closed as too broad.

For your first question, all variables have an initial default value. From the [Solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/types.html#mappings):

> Mappings can be seen as hash tables which are virtually initialized such that every possible key exists and is mapped to a value whose byte-representation is all zeros: a type’s default value.

No storage is used for zero values.

For your second question, you're overwriting the state variable because you're using a `storage` variable where you should be using a `memory` variable. See the answer provided here: [what are state variables in solidity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49613580/what-are-state-variables-in-solidity/49620359#49620359)